# Multiple background images using css3 and sprites

Tags: css

Is there any way to apply multiple background images using sprites?
something like the below code?

```
background-image: url("../images/button-sprite.gif"),url("../images/button-sprite.gif");
background-position: right -92px, 0px 0px ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-size: 1em;
margin-right: 5px;
padding-right: 35px;
width:500px;
height:500px
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple background images

see the [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/qPvj4/1/)

Here is my css:

```
.sprite_box
{
        background: 
        url(http://i.imgur.com/On0lt.png) -162px -551px no-repeat,
        url(http://i.imgur.com/On0lt.png) -200px -530px no-repeat,        
        transparent;     
        height: 24px;    
        width: 81px;
        margin:5px;
}​
```

Read about [sprite here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

[Here you can create sprite image](http://csssprites.com/)
[Here you create css for your sprite image](http://www.spritebox.net)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have multiple background images, but it is limited to box items.  There is some info on this at [CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. The shorthand method is less verbose:

```
.sprite {
  background: 
    url(http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo41.png) 0 -243px no-repeat,
    url(http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo41.png) 42px -93px no-repeat,
    #ccc;
  width: 160px;
}
```

Note that you can only state one background color, and you state it at the end of the declaration.

See it in aciton http://jsfiddle.net/TMHPh/