# syntax help - background image sprite css

Tags: css, coordinates, background-image, css-sprites

I know I'm close but someone help me out:

```
body {
background-attachment: fixed;
background: url("images/background.jpg"), url("images/background.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
line-height: 1;
min-width: 1150px;
background-position: top left, bottom right;
}
```

The image being used as a sprite, "background.jpg" is 1720px wide by 1100px tall. I need to show the top right part of the image in the first instance and the bottom left part of the image in the second instance. In each case the size of the rectangle needed to be taken from the jpg is 600px wide and 400px tall.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364643/css-two-background-images-using-a-sprite with the image file names swapped out for something else entirely and different background positions.

Comment: Whilst this relates to that post it's a new question on the specific syntax needed to select the desired coordinates of an image

Answer (score 2):

This may help

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: url("images/background.jpg") 100% 0px no-repeat, url("images/background.jpg") 0% 600px no-repeat;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 1150px;
    }
```

Play about with the values after the images. The 100% and 0% refer to the x axis (these can also be px) and the 0px 600px refer to the y axis. Without having a live page to play about with this is as much as I can tell you.

Comment: Ok I'm working myself into confusion. Do the coordinates after the url relate to which part of the image to select or to where to place the selected part of the image? I'm confusing myself between how to position top left and bottom right for each section of the image and on where to select. For simplicity say I have a square that is 1000px on each side and I wish to select a square that is 100px in size from the bottom left of the sprite and position it in the top right of the browser. How? Hope I'm making sense!

Comment: To do that you would have the following background: url("images/background.jpg") 900px -900px no-repeat. the coordinates relate to where the image is positioned. So this is 900px from the left and -900px from the top. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also the coordinates are relative to the parent container.

Comment: Ok thanks for info. So based on what you say the following code:

body {
    background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat scroll -460px 0px, url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0px -1000px ;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 1150px;
    background-position: top right, bottom left;
}
 
would mean select the part of the fist image taken from sprite at -460px from the right and start at the top, position it in the top right. Then select that part of the sprite that begins immediately at the right and is 1000px down from the top. Place this part in the bottom left.

correct?

Comment: I should have mentioned you don't need the background-position: top right, bottom left; as this will supersede the background-position you have already declared after the image i.e -460px 0px, 0px -1000px; The way CSS works is through the cascade and whatever is declared further down the stylesheet takes precedence over something that is declared above it.

Comment: ah I see that was boggling. So wait. I now know how to select the right part of the image - I think (and thank you) but how do I place it in the right place? i.e. I'm taking two images (sections) from the sprite. Now that they are selected how do I tell the browser where to place them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10647/discussion-between-doug-firr-and-trickeedickee)